# infinite ramification locus in towers of function fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is well known that there are conditions on the roots of the polynomial equation that arises from a recursive tower of function fields over a finite field implying the finiteness of the ramification locus of the (recursive) tower. Does anybody know of conditions on the defining polynomial equation of a recursive tower implying infinite ramification locus?
Thanks!
ricardo